# How to get the registered sidebar's name by its id?

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, themes, widgets

Let's say I have this code in my *"functions.php"*:

```
function mytheme_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar Name', 'mytheme' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => '',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'mytheme_widgets_init' );
```

How can I get that sidebar name by its id, some kind of this code?

```
get_dynamic_sidebar_name( 'sidebar-2' ); // -> Sidebar Name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sidebars are stored in global variable `$wp_registered_sidebars`. You can get the sidebar properties using this variable.

```
global $wp_registered_sidebars;
if ( isset( $wp_registered_sidebars['sidebar-2'] ) ) { 
    echo $wp_registered_sidebars['sidebar-2']['name'];
}
```

> Note that do not use it too early, either on/after `widgets_init` hook
>   or in a template file.